# QLabel Style Sheet not change before the execution of loop in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I want to change the background color of my QLabel. On clicking the label, label connects to an event that sets the label color to `Red` and loop runs for 3 second after 3 seconds and completion on loops the color of label should change to `Yellow`
This is the code:

```
from PyQt5.uic   import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QDialog,QLabel
import sys
import time

def sleep4three():
            for i in range(3):
                  print('inside the loop')
                  time.sleep(1)

class main(QDialog):

  def __init__(self):
        super(main,self).__init__()
        loadUi('untitled.ui',self)
        self.l.mousePressEvent = self.connect_
  def connect_(self,event):
        time.sleep(2)
        ss = 'QLabel{background-color:red;}'
        self.l.setStyleSheet(ss)

        for i in range(3):
              time.sleep(1)
              
        self.l.setStyleSheet('QLabel{background-color:yellow;}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
      app = QApplication(sys.argv)
      main_ = main()
      main_.show()
      app.exec_()
```

But what's happening is the color of label `l` never changes to `Red` the execution directly jumps to the loop and i only see yellow colored `l`

Comment: You cannot use blocking functions in the main UI loop. Please explain what should happen there so we could eventually provide you with more practical solutions.

Comment: This one is a test file. Originally i want to create a loading label. I want load data and process from a csv and while data loads i want to let the user know that we are currently processing your data and after processing we have to notify the user that execution is completed

Comment: If the data loading doesn't take a lot of time, use QApplication.processEvents() right after any update you want to see on the UI, but don't overuse it. If the time required is long (more than 5-10 seconds) and the loading allows it (no direct UI interaction until the process is finished), then you could consider threading.

Comment: it will take about 10secs. I guess multi-threading is the only option. But can you tell me why i was not able to see red color? in the code mentioned above?

Comment: No, it's not the *only* option, is a *possible* option. 10 seconds is quite bearable for calling `QApplication.processEvents()` a few times. If you can do that periodically (each iteration of a loop, or each n* iteration if the loop has too many entries), that's fine. The code above doesn't work because a blocking function prevents the UI loop to properly process its events, including *updating* the UI. That's what `processEvents()` does: reads all queued events, and handles them.

Comment: I did a work around for this case. update the label to ```processing the data``` before calling the function and called the ```processEvents``` and after execution of function updated the label again to ```proccessing finished```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tiny reproducible adaptation of your code that is also a demonstration of using `QApplication.processEvents()` as was discussed in the comments.  Hopefully this helps.

When this function is called it essentially pauses the execution of your code so that the GUI can process it's signals and updates and before resuming again.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import time

class main(QDialog):

  def __init__(self):
        super(main,self).__init__()
        self.l = QLabel("label", self)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.l)
        self.l.mousePressEvent = self.connect_

  def connect_(self,event):
        ss = 'QLabel{background-color:%s;}'
        color = iter(["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "white"])
        self.l.setStyleSheet(ss % next(color))
        QApplication.processEvents()
        time.sleep(2)
        for _ in range(3):
            self.l.setStyleSheet(ss % next(color))
            QApplication.processEvents()
            time.sleep(1)
        self.l.setStyleSheet(ss % next(color))
        return super().mousePressEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
      app = QApplication(sys.argv)
      main_ = main()
      main_.show()
      app.exec_()
```